# Examples of how to a STS in .Net 4.5 using WCF

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

I'm looking for Examples of how to a STS in .Net 4.5 using WCF.

So the scenario is I have a MVC 4 web app that I want to write an STS to authenticate and get claims that stores its data in the traditional SqlMembershipProvider database schema that we all know and love.

I'm guessing the STS could be a simple WCF service.

I've googled around but can only find stuff that shows how to do all this when the WIF was separated from the Core Framework. I.e. before it was embedded in .Net 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your solution may not be as easy as you expect it to be. Have a look at https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2 which is a .NET STS. I guess using it will suffice in your case and it is very actively developed.

Comment: Once I got it up and running I couldn't see how to add a SQL Identity Provider. Any tips there

Comment: Docs say _"IdSrv uses the "classic" ASP.NET providers by default, but includes the ASP.NET Universal Provider NuGet package. These newer providers support all editions of SQL Server from 2005 to SQL Azure (including SQL Compact). To switch to these providers, uncomment them in web.config (in the membership, roles and profile section)."_