# Build an Active STS using WCF in .net 4.5

Tags: wcf, wif

I have a scenario whereby i need to build a WCF service to provide custom authentication to 3rd parties non-web application connecting in an "Active" mode - i.e. i cannot present a web login page.

The login mechanism is also custom (i.e. not necessarily username/password), and so i cannot use ADFS or ACS.

I have read up on building active STS using WCF, but they mostly relate to .NET 3.5 and not much has been written around using .NET 4.5 since WIF has been integrated into the framework.

I have read [Examples of how to a STS in .Net 4.5 using WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851683/examples-of-how-to-a-sts-in-net-4-5-using-wcf) but it doesn't seem to fit my scenario.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: Ended up using thinktecture - why reinvent the wheel when thinktecture provided a solid wheel, free of charge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to have a look at

http://thinktecture.github.com/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/

This is an open source STS that includes active endpoints.

Comment: Hi Dominick. I had a quick look at IdSrv but the video suggested it was for web based scenario, i didnt realise it could do Active endpoints as well. I cannot see anything in the documentation that would suggest that it could and how to acheive it https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/wiki

Comment: When you take a look at the configuration UI, you can enable/disable WS-Trust endpoints.